# Add an image field from buildForm() with preview

Tags: 8, forms, media

I created a custom form, and I would like add an image field.

I can do that via this code.

```
$form['main']['image'] = array(
  '#type' => 'managed_file',
  '#title' => t('image'),
  '#default_value' => array(10),
);
```

I can upload and remove the image from my form. However, when I upload an image, I haven't this preview.
I mean, when I create a content via the Drupal UI. I can add a pre-configured "image" field. When I upload an image via this "image" field, I have a preview of the image.

And here, when I create the field element programmatically, I haven't a preview of the image when I upload it.
What code should I use to get the preview of the image when I upload it via my *image* field?

Comment: You are creating a text_format field, which is not an image field.

Comment: This is the same question that's been asked a dozen or more times for D7 - how can you use a field widget outside of an entity form. I don't think it was made any easier but hopefully I'm wrong

Comment: Not a text_field, sorry, its a bad copy/paste -_- I update my post

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/167890/how-to-display-image-preview-right-away-for-managed-file-form-element

Comment: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/212480/drupal-8-form-api-image-preview/