# Form API image preview

Tags: 8, forms, media

I've read many discussions about image preview in fapi with `'managed_file'`, but I can't find a conclusive answer on how to do this properly in D8.

An obvious solution would be to reuse `Drupal\image\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget\ImageWidget`, but I don't know how to accomplish this.

So my question is: how can I have an image upload field with image preview in my form in D8 and what would the associative array in my `buildForm` function look like?

Answer (score 16):

After searching for a while, I have found some kind of workaround solution for this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38268567/2267244

I have tested it and it works, here is bit modified version which I have used.

Also I'm not sure if we should mark this question as dpulicate as I found the solution on stackoverflow.com.

Anyway Here is how your form field should looke like:

```
$form['image_with_preview'] = [
  '#type' => 'managed_file',
  '#title' => t('Image with preview'),
  '#upload_validators' => [
    'file_validate_extensions' => ['gif png jpg jpeg'],
    'file_validate_size' => [25600000],
  ],
  '#theme' => 'image_widget',
  '#preview_image_style' => 'medium',
  '#upload_location' => 'public://',
  '#required' => FALSE,
];
```

And also you will need to implement `hook_preprocess_HOOK` in your module like this:

```
function YOUR_MODULE_preprocess_image_widget(&$variables) {
    $element = $variables['element'];

    $variables['attributes'] = array('class' => array('image-widget', 'js-form-managed-file', 'form-managed-file', 'clearfix'));

    if (!empty($element['fids']['#value'])) {
      $file = reset($element['#files']);
      $element['file_' . $file->id()]['filename']['#suffix'] = ' <span class="file-size">(' . format_size($file->getSize()) . ')</span> ';
      $file_variables = array(
        'style_name' => $element['#preview_image_style'],
        'uri' => $file->getFileUri(),
      );

      // Determine image dimensions.
      if (isset($element['#value']['width']) && isset($element['#value']['height'])) {
        $file_variables['width'] = $element['#value']['width'];
        $file_variables['height'] = $element['#value']['height'];
      } else {
        $image = \Drupal::service('image.factory')->get($file->getFileUri());
        if ($image->isValid()) {
          $file_variables['width'] = $image->getWidth();
          $file_variables['height'] = $image->getHeight();
        }
        else {
          $file_variables['width'] = $file_variables['height'] = NULL;
        }
      }

      $element['preview'] = array(
        '#weight' => -10,
        '#theme' => 'image_style',
        '#width' => $file_variables['width'],
        '#height' => $file_variables['height'],
        '#style_name' => $file_variables['style_name'],
        '#uri' => $file_variables['uri'],
      );

      // Store the dimensions in the form so the file doesn't have to be
      // accessed again. This is important for remote files.
      $element['width'] = array(
        '#type' => 'hidden',
        '#value' => $file_variables['width'],
      );
      $element['height'] = array(
        '#type' => 'hidden',
        '#value' => $file_variables['height'],
      );
    }

    $variables['data'] = array();
    foreach (\Drupal\Core\Render\Element::children($element) as $child) {
      $variables['data'][$child] = $element[$child];
    }
}
```

I have tested it on my local Drupal instance and it works fine, image preview was displayed after AJAX upload finished.

Comment: still works in 2023 in Drupal 10 :) thanks for this!